# How to return observable of values emitted by inner observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to return observable of whatever is the response of inner observable.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5gpfwd9y/1/)

```
  function Resolver() {
var x="5";

 var ob1= Rx.Observable.of(1).delay(2000);

 ob1.subscribe(d=>{
    if(d=='something'){
     x=x*10;
    }
    else{
    x=x*20;
    }
     console.log(x);
  });

 return Rx.Observable.of(
  x
  );
}
console.clear();
var mydata= Resolver().subscribe(data => {
 console.log(data)
});
```

The above code returns 5 first and 100 later. I just want to return 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather use `map` operator instead of subscribing.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

function Resolver() {
  ...
  return ob1.pipe(map(d=>{
    if(d == 'something') {
      return x * 10;
    } else {
      return x * 20;
    }
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the `map` operator since I don't see your need for an inner observable. In case of an inner observable you can use the `switchMap` operator, this maps the inner observable result to the outer observable. For instance:

```
function Resolver() {
  var x=5;

  return Rx.Observable.of(1).delay(2000).pipe(
    map(data => {
      if(d=='something'){
        x=x*10;
      }
      else{
        x=x*20;
      }
      return x;
    });
  );
}
```